# CSS Menu Item shifted to left and drop-down is not showing

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to migrate the menu from my wordpress [installation](http://bit.ly/68JqER) to a non-wordpress site.

I stripped down css and html, and put it all in [jsfiddle](http://bit.ly/14UPuJu) too.

I ran ito 2 problems:

1) For some reason the first menu item is shifted to the right and I spent entire evening trying to figure it out.

2) The drop-down is not showing :(

I tried to post code here but its too big and keeps breaking the formatting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: I added the JQuery for drop down which I found already in your website when I viewed page source.

http://jsfiddle.net/F7SjC/1/

```
 $("#accessm ul li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp('fast');
  }
);
```

you need JS to show the drop down functionality. I am not sure what you mean by your 1) menu item shift.

Comment: Woot it worked with dropdown :) first li in the menu is shifted to the right for some reason, thats what I meant :)